Edit icon in mobile view missing
When I go to mobile responsive view in a web browser the Edit pencil icon currently doesn’t show under the ‘Attachments’ column if the name of the file is really long like in the picture below. I found where the problem is in the developer tools. It is in the span class called d-flex. When I uncheck .d-flex: display: flex !important the icon shows. In the code solution there currently isn’t a scss file so what would be the best way to handle this to get the icon to show based off of what I found. Create a new scss file to handle showing the icon when in mobile view only like @media only screen? If so how would I set that up in the scss file?
Here are the two pics before and after removing the .d-flex css rule


And this is the code for the column with the span tag
 <ng-template #transactionAttachmentsCell let-row="transaction">
 <span class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
     <ng-container *ngIf="hasWriteAccess || row.attachments?.length > 0; else 
    emptyCell">
        <app-button *ngIf="row.attachments?.length > 0"
                    type="link"
                    icon="{{ row.attachments[0].matIcon.icon }}"
                    iconColor="{{ row.attachments[0].matIcon.color }}"
                    [iconTooltip]="row.attachments[0].filename"
                    (onClick)="$event.stopPropagation(); 
         openAttachment(row.attachments[0].url)">
            {{ (row.attachments[0].filename | truncateFilename: 18) }}
        </app-button>
        <app-icon-button *ngIf="hasWriteAccess"
                         [icon]="row.attachments?.length > 1 ? 'more_vert' : 
           (row.attachments?.length > 0 ? 'edit' : 'add')"
                         [iconTooltip]="row.attachments?.length > 1 ? ('+' + 
          (row.attachments.length - 1) + ' Additional Attachment' + 
               (row.attachments.length - 1 === 1 
           ? '' : 's')) : null"
                         (onClick)="$event.stopPropagation(); 
       showManageAttachmentsDialog(row)">
        </app-icon-button>
      </ng-container>
    </span>
</ng-template>


As you are using Boostrap class d-flex so that is why you found display: flex !important; in developer tools. Try using flex-wrap in <span> along with other classes, it may help to move icon below the filename and display both, filename and icon.

Add fixed width to file name so that it leave room for edit icon and image icon both. Currently edit icons is getting overflowed which led it to not showing.
